# Proving $\,\sin^272^\circ - \sin^260^\circ = \frac18\left(\sqrt5 - 1\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm fairly new into proving trigonometric equations, but I believe I'm getting better at it day after day. Yet, I have stumbled upon one such which left me at an impasse. The problem is presented as follows:
$$\sin^272^\circ - \sin^260^\circ = \dfrac{\sqrt5 - 1}8$$

The goal is to prove the truth of the so-presented equation. I first complicated the right-hand side of the equation to $\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}4\cdot\dfrac12$ to then simplify it into $\sin18^\circ\cdot\sin30^\circ$ (knowing, of course, that $\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}4$ is equal to $\sin18^\circ$, and that $\dfrac12$ is equal to $\sin30^\circ$).

I then proceeded to work the proof from the left-hand side, now that both sides of the equation are termed in trigonometric ratios. The left-hand side is easily noticed to be a difference of squares, hence being apt for complication as $(\sin72^\circ - \sin60^\circ)(\sin72^\circ + \sin60^\circ)$. It is only a coincidence to notice that the expressions can be further simplified knowing the sum/difference to product rule (i.e. that $\sin A + \sin B = 2\sin\dfrac{A + B}2\cos\dfrac{A - B}2$, and also that  $\sin A - \sin B =2\cos\dfrac{A + B}2\sin\dfrac{A - B}2$).

Executing these simplifications, we get the next result: $2\sin66^\circ\cdot\cos66^\circ\cdot2\sin6^\circ\cdot\cos6^\circ$. It is evident to see how the double angle rules could be of use here (that $2\sin\theta\cos\theta =\sin2\theta$). The penultimate result with this rule applied is thus, so far: $\sin132^\circ\cdot\sin12^\circ$. I can only go as far as to simply right the ratios in terms of angles less that $45$ degrees, which is: $\cos42^\circ\cdot\sin12^\circ$.

For the most of it, I am stuck; and any rules I apply to simplify either expression gets me to a result previously acquired in the run. How am I to finish proving that $\cos42^\circ\cdot\sin12^\circ$ is equal to $\sin18^\circ\cdot\sin30^\circ$, or equivalently $\sin18^\circ\cdot\cos60^\circ$. This problem can be found in S.L Loney's book on plane trigonometry, a really helpful book for getting a good picture on trigonometry. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2t=\frac{1-\cos(2t)}2,$ and (in radians) $-\cos\frac{4\pi}5=\cos\frac\pi5=\frac{1+\sqrt5}4.$

Comment: Are you assumed to already know the trig functions at 12° or 18°, or just the traditional "special" angles of 0°, 30°, 45°, 60°, and 90°?

Comment: the book already derived the 9 degree angle and all its multiples; those are the 18. 36. 54. 72 degree angles.

Answer (score 3):

Now

$$\sin^2 72°=\cos^2(90°-72°)=\cos^2(18°)=\frac{1+\cos36°}{2}=\frac{1+\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{4}}{2}$$

$$=\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{8}$$

Thus

$$\sin^2 60°=\frac 34$$
Hence

$$\color{orange}{\sin^272^\circ - \sin^260^\circ} = \frac{5+\sqrt 5}{8}-\frac 34=\frac{5+\sqrt 5-6}{8}=\color{red}{\frac18\left(\sqrt5 - 1\right)}$$

Comment: It only now seems obvious, thank you for the simple and concise point you have provided me with.

Comment: @Camelot823 You're welcome $\cdots\smile$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin^2t=\frac{1-\cos(2t)}2\quad\text{ and }\quad\cos(s°)=-\cos((180-s)°)$$
hence
$$\begin{align}\sin^2(72°)-\sin^2(60)&=\frac{\cos(120)-\cos(144°)}2\\
&=\frac{\cos(36°)-\cos(60°)}2\\
&=\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt 5}4-\frac12}2\\
&=\frac{\sqrt 5-1}8.\end{align}$$

Comment: I believe I may have overthinked what appears to be a fairly simple question. Thank you for the elucidation you have provided.